# Nested Web Compontent render multipli

Tags: javascript, web-component

I just start building my first Web Compontent. I want to understand those frameworks out there and I start from scratch

MyProblem ist that the Components are rendering multipli times. So I have some parts more than once in a nested element.

An example will show you what is going wrong.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <wc-form>
            <wc-box>
                <wc-input></wc-input>
            </wc-box>
           
        </wc-form>
        <script type="module">
            import {Input} from './js/input.js'; 
            import {Form} from './js/form.js';
            import {Box} from './js/box.js';
            
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Every Import i one of this Web Compontent I create like these one example

```js
export class Form extends HTMLElement {
    
    constructor() {
        super()
 
} 
    
    
    render() {
        this.innerHTML = `
            <form style="border:5tpx solid green">
            ${this.innerHTML}
            </form>`
    } 
}

window.customElements.define('wc-form', Form);
```

So I developed the slots function with the output from innerHTML. When I run this code I get nested boxes multipli because some parts are often rendered than ones. That is because I use the innerHTMl so so script always starts to render again and again.

When i do the import the right way as the elements can be strucred I don't get the Problem.

Comment: Make 1 parent component that has all the child components inside of it. And only render the parent component once.

Comment: I think we later have 100+ from the boxes with different slots. I can't build for every box a new element.  Or did i miss understand you?

Comment: Both your SO snippets do not work, could you add something that replicates your issue